# How to make a bar plot of my data frame using ggplot2()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stack, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot using ggplot() function. I have this data frame:

```
  25% - 75%   5% - 95%  Out of Confidence Band  leadtime
1  49.91055   89.80322              10.196780      2 hr
2  50.08945   89.80322              10.196780     12 hr
3  49.73166   89.80322              10.196780     24 hr
4  49.91055   90.16100               9.838998     32 hr
5  50.08945   89.80322              10.196780     50 hr
6  49.73166   89.62433              10.375671     62 hr
```

I want to show for every Leadtime its three respective values (25-75%, 5-95%, Out of confidence Band) in bars. So at the end I will have 6 group of bars.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if you want stacked bars, if so - here you go. I changed the shape of the dataframe to make plotting easier.

```
dat <- data.frame(leadtime  = rep(c(2,12,24,32,50,62),each=3), 
percent = rep(c("25-75","5-95", "OoC"), 6), 
value = c(49.91055, 89.80322, 10.196780,50.08945, 89.80322, 10.196780, 
49.73166, 89.80322, 10.196780, 49.91055, 90.16100, 9.838998, 50.08945,
89.80322, 10.196780, 49.73166, 89.62433, 10.375671))

ggplot(dat, aes(leadtime, value, fill = percent))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Comment: I indeed need a bars plot, no stacked bar.

Comment: Then use ` position = 'dodge'` within the geom_bar component - per the guide http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_dodge.html

Comment: Thanks so much! It ran ok

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to reshape the dataset via something like `melt` rather than typing out the reshaped format by hand?

Comment: using the format of the original dataframe posted by @Rayner. `library(reshape2)` then `newdata<- melt(data, id.vars = 'leadtime')` then `ggplot(newdata, aes(leadtime, value, fill = variable))+geom_bar(stat='identity', position = 'dodge')`